# Chaining JS methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert some whitespace in a string if the string conforms to a certain format. Specifically, if the string consists of only numbers, and is exactly five characters in length, whitespace should be added between the third and fourth numbers.

[Here's my test case:](http://jsfiddle.net/LwAg9/)

```
function codeAddress() {
    var num_regex = /^\d+$/,
            input = $("#distributor-search").val(),
          address = (input.match(num_regex) && input.length == 5) ? input.split('').splice(3, 0 , ' ').join() : input ;

    console.log('The address is: ' + address);

    return false;
}
```

For some reason, chaining `.split()`, `.splice()` and `.join()` seems to not return anything. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's your input value?

Comment: Any five-digit string, _i.e._, '12345'. Did you look at the jsFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have explained, your function didn't work because `.splice()` returns the removed elements, instead of the resulting array.

Try using this regex, instead:

```
/^(\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/
```

It will only match a string if it's 5 digits long, it won't modify other strings.

Examples:

```
var s = '123456'.replace(/^(\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/, '$1 $2');
// "123456"
var s = '1234'.replace(/^(\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/, '$1 $2');
// "1234"
var s = '12345'.replace(/^(\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/, '$1 $2');
// "123 45"
```

So, in your case:

```
address = $("#distributor-search").val().replace(/^(\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/, '$1 $2');
```

Answer (score 7):

[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an array, [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the array with the **removed** elements and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns the joined array like they should.

Looks like everything goes wrong at `splice()`. Instead of giving the remainders, you get the removed items.

My test:

```
var input = '123,789';
var output = input.split(',').splice(1, 0, '456').join(',');

console.log(output); // outputs nothing, because `splice(1, 0, '456')` doesn't remove any values
```

You could solve this by making a prototype that uses splice's functionality, like so:

```
Array.prototype.isplice = function() {
    var tmp = this;

    Array.prototype.splice.apply(tmp, Array.prototype.isplice.arguments);

    return tmp;
};

var output = input.split(',').isplice(1, 0, '456').join(',');
console.log(output); // outputs ["123", "456", "789"] as expected
```

Comment: +1 for a nice and simple explanation of what the functions actually do and why it is not working as expected.

Comment: It's quite strange that I got the idea to insert elements to an array [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Their first example seems to add an element without removing anything.

Comment: @JezenThomas You should use `.push()` to add elements!

Comment: @JezenThomas Ah! That appears to be the problem! Because `splice()` returns an array of removed items, it returns nothing (because you aren't removing anything). If you use my prototype it should work fine. That trick is a genuine way to add elements somewhere in your array though.

Comment: This solution is clever but in my opinion you should refrain from mangling with built-in objects and implement it into a object of your own or as a stand-alone function. This is because the built-in objects are global and that can create compatibility issues within code or other libraries you use.

Comment: @GerardoLima Well-built libraries rarely rely on prototyping so I shouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the regex itself?

```
var num_regex = /^(\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/,
        input = $("#distributor-search").val(),
      address = input.match(num_regex);
if (address) address = address[1] + ' ' + address[2];
```

That regex matches a five-digit string and groups the first three and last two digits together.  If the test string matches, then the `.match()` function returns an array with the two groups in positions 1 and 2 (position 0 being the entire match).

Comment: Imo, if you're going to use a regex to replace something, why not use `.replace()` while you're at it?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes that's a good point - depends on what other things are going on with the parts of the value; if nothing, then a replace is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate splice with join in your case:

```
splice(3, 0 , ' ').join()
```

remember that splice returns a new array containing the removed items, not the result array.